# How to figure out pipe buffer is full?

Tags: linux

I wonder there is a linux utility to report pipe buffer usage or not.

When I use subprocess module of python, sometime the subprocess is blocked because OS pipe buffer becomes full. When it happens, I usually spend significant amount to time to reason the buffer is full by guessing. So, I want to know there is much easier way to find out OS pipe buffer is full.

Thanks

Comment: While the normal way is to use non-blocking I/O, which allows you to detect it, why is that a problem for you ? pipes are designed to block when they're full. What do you want to do when it's full ?

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be interested in that. You should design your program such that it works even when the buffer fills: most reasonable programs should just wait and they get unblocked when the reader reads from the pipe.

That said, in python you can use `os.O_NONBLOCK`. When you do **a write which would block** `os.write` should instead return immediately with `EAGAIN`. From the linux man page:

> `EAGAIN` The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket and
>   has been  marked  nonblocking  (`O_NONBLOCK`), and the write would
>   block.

But like `nos` asked, once you know a write would block, what else is there to do instead of just waiting for the buffer to drain ?

Comment: Thanks @cnicutar. I tried to make some scripts to control QEMU. To do that, I redirected stdin/out of the QEMU process to pipes using subprocess. At that time, I forgot drain the pipes and suddenly QEMU process stopped. It took several hours to figure out that the reason the process stop was pipeline full. Thus, I just wanted to know there is some quick method to identify such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `ulimit -p` tells you.

```
$ ulimit -p
8

$ ulimit -a | grep pipe
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
```

Here the size of pipe buffer is 512 bytes. But you can not know is it full or not by and command.